# How can I implement a multi-language switch in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

In my current project, **I'm developing a multi-language site using nuxt.js. While the `i18n` solution is available, my approach doesn't focus on translating English terms into Spanish or other languages. My goal is to build separate pages for each language within dedicated directories.** The default language will be English, and I plan to create a directory named `es` to host all the Spanish pages. This directory might have the following structure:

```
pages
├── index.vue
├── somepage.vue
└── es
    ├── index.vue
    └── somepage.vue
```

The **default English pages** are accessible through `example.com` and `example.com/somepage`, while the **equivalent Spanish homepag and pages** are accessed via `example.com/es` and `example.com/es/somepage`.

My main query is: **How can I integrate a language-switching dropdown for users?** Your assistance in resolving this matter would be highly appreciated. Despite conducting thorough online research, **most of the solutions I came across were related to i18n**. Can i18n handle this specific scenario, or is there an alternative approach? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### Providing Different Routes for Language Switching

**So your main question is not about how to switch languages, but rather about how to load different components when the language parameter in the route changes.**

If you insist on showing the language in the URL, you need to clarify this in Vue Router as well. Your main route will only be `/:lang`, which allows you to include the language in every sub-route. Your actual pages will be sub-routes of this. You will need to import the components dynamically, using the `:lang` variable and the appropriate file path that corresponds to your own file structure.

**Here's an example of how to implement this approach:**

```js
/**
 ** Get Component
 */
const getComponentByLang = (resolve, route, componentPath) => {
  const lang = route.params.lang;
  return import(`./pages/${lang}/${componentPath}.vue`).then((component) => {
    resolve(component);
  });
};

/**
 ** Routes
 */
const routes: [
  // Main Route (/es or /en ...)
  {
    path: '/:lang',
    children: [
      // Sub Route (/es/articles/title or /en/articles/title ...)
      // Load /langFolder/Articles/Show.vue
      {
        path: '/articles/:name',
        component: (resolve, route) => getComponentByLang(resolve, route, 'Articles/Show')
      },
      // Sub Route (/es/topics/title or /en/topics/title ...)
      // Load /langFolder/Topics/Index.vue
      {
        path: '/topics/:name',
        component: (resolve, route) => getComponentByLang(resolve, route, 'Topics/Index')
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

More informations:

[Nested Routes on Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

[Lazy Component Loading on Vue-Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

---

It is necessary to place every component in its own language folder, including the English one.

```
# normal directory tree
server
├── your-project
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── en
│   │   │   ├── index.vue
│   │   │   └── somepage.vue
│   │   └── es
│   │       ├── index.vue
│   │       └── somepage.vue
│   ├── ...
```

```js
const getComponentByLang = (resolve, route, componentPath) => {
  const lang = route.params.lang;
  return import(`./pages/${lang}/${componentPath}.vue`).then((component) => {
    resolve(component);
  });
};
```

Alternatively, you can declare the English language as an exception when defining the component's path.

```
# normal directory tree
server
├── your-project
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── index.vue
│   │   ├── somepage.vue
│   │   └── es
│   │       ├── index.vue
│   │       └── somepage.vue
│   ├── ...
```

```js
const getComponentByLang = (resolve, route) => {
  const lang = route.params.lang;
  const path = lang === 'en' ? `./pages/${componentPath}.vue` : `./pages/${lang}/${componentPath}.vue`
  return import(path).then((component) => {
    resolve(component);
  });
};
```

---

### Language selection in both cases

In broad strokes... You need an array listing the selectable languages. Then, you create a dropdown menu where you populate the options from that array. Upon value change in the dropdown, you invoke a language selection function. Assuming you have translations for ALL your pages, within this function, you'll replace the "language" part of the current URL with the selected language. So, for instance, if the current URL is `example.com/en/articles/mycurrenttitle`, after selecting a new language, the URL will become `example.com/es/articles/mycurrenttitle`.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="language">Select Language:</label>
    <select id="language" v-model="selectedLanguage" @change="changeLanguage">
      <option v-for="language in languages" :value="language.value" :key="language.value">{{ language.label }}</option>
    </select>

    <p>Current URL: {{ currentUrl }}</p>
    <p>Selected Language: {{ selectedLanguage }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const languages = ref([
  { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
  { label: 'Español', value: 'es' }
]);
const selectedLanguage = ref('');
const currentUrl = ref('');

const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();

const changeLanguage = () => {
  if (selectedLanguage.value) {
    const newUrl = route.path.replace(/^\/(en|es)/, `/${selectedLanguage.value}`);
    router.push(newUrl);
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  currentUrl.value = route.path;
  const langMatch = currentUrl.value.match(/^\/(en|es)/);
  selectedLanguage.value = langMatch ? langMatch[1] : '';
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

use vue-multilanguage plugin
for reference check here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-multilanguage